# win32-g++ error on for_each and lambda

Tags: foreach, lambda, g++

I know this theme often turns up on stackoverflow, but the case here is different:
The following code compiles with MsVC++ 2013 but not with win32-g++. Is there any way of making it work with both compilers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    vector<int>my_vector;
    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        my_vector.push_back(i);
    for_each( my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), [ ](int  n){cout<<n;});
    return 0;
}
```

The errors reported are

```
||=== stdtest, Debug ===|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp|13|warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp|13|error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, main()::<lambda(int)>)'|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp|13|note: candidate is:|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4436|note: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp|13|error: template argument for 'template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)' uses local type 'main()::<lambda(int)>'|
D:\dev\CplusPlus\stdtest\main.cpp|13|error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I should add that I am assuming that the C++11 standard is turned on because "enabled by default". In case I am wrong, I am having a hard time finding out how to change the compiler switches from Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that I was misled by the statement that -sdd=C++11 was "enabled by default". 
I ended up finding a way of turning it on with the Project > Build Options> compiler settings
and then I clicked on the checkbox "have g++ follow the c++11 ISO C++ language settings" checkbox.

For those who are working with QtCreator add the following line to the project file:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11